# Discord.JS: Array resets itself after some time

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

Some days ago, I programmed a Discord bot with a count game. Someone has to send 1, then someone else had to say 2 and so on. When someone said a number twice, or said the wrong number, the game started all over again. When someone says the wrong number, the bot returns what the number had to be.

However, I noticed something was wrong. Some people said the following number, but it appeared the array was resetted. The bot returned the following number to be 1. It already happened a lot of times.

The code:

```
var counter = [{
    name: "bot",
    nummer: 0
}];
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id == "804378504300200016") {
        if(!isNaN(message.content)){
            var counterlast = counter[counter.length - 1];
            var countercheck = counterlast["nummer"] + 1;
            var pinger = parseInt(message.content);
            var lastuser = counterlast["name"];
            if(countercheck === pinger && lastuser !== message.author.id){
                counter.push({name: message.author.id, nummer: countercheck});
                message.react('✅');
            }
            else{
                if(lastuser === message.author.id){
                    message.react('⚠️');
                    message.reply(`Chappie, niet nog een keer. Volgend nummer is 1`);
                    counter.length = 0;
                    counter.push({name: "bot", nummer: 0});
                }
                else{
                    message.react('⚠️');
                    message.reply(`Chappie, verkeerd nummer. Het moest ${countercheck} zijn. Volgend nummer is 1.`);
                    counter.length = 0;
                    counter.push({name: "bot", nummer: 0});
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I have actually no clue what the problem could be. Does someone has a alternative method or the solution?

My bot is running on a Ubuntu server with 1vCPU & 1Gb ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. Something other files in my server caused a restart, so the array reset itself. After solving those files, my server did not cause any crash so the counting continues.

Also, I found that a better approach would be to use a `.json` file instead. So when the server has to restart, the progress will stay saved.